# Write dataframe to table in Teradata from R using RODBC sqlSave

Tags: r, teradata

This is a legacy R code that is running for months. I was able to read/drop a table in Teradata from R but not able to write data into the table from data frame.

I have tried by dropping table and recreating and writing different dataframe.

```
sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = paste("scenario.table_storetype"),rownames=F)
```

I was getting the following error

> Error in sqlColumns(channel, tablename)[4L][, 1L]: incorrect number of
>   dimensions Traceback: 
>   1. sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = paste("scenario.table_storetype"),   .     rownames = F, safer = FALSE, append = T) 
>   2. sqlwrite(channel, tablename, dat, verbose = verbose, fast = fast,   .     test = test, nastring = nastring)

```
dput(head(df))
```

**Output**:
structure(list(forecast = c(36659805.75, 28117111.75, 27005618.75, 
33650734.4166667, 27243750.75, 26907919.0833333), actual = c(38293943, 
29892143, 27016674, 33524728, 27252399, 26521098), BC = c("Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", 
"Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", "Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", 
"Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", "Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", 
"Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg"), period = 201904:201909, how = c("a_tslm_mape", 
"a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape"
)), .Names = c("forecast", "actual", "BC", "period", "how"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

```
dput(head(df))
```

**After rounding off - Output**:
structure(list(forecast = c(36659805.75, 28117111.75, 27005618.75, 
33650734.42, 27243750.75, 26907919.08), actual = c(38293943, 
29892143, 27016674, 33524728, 27252399, 26521098), BC = c("Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", 
"Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", "Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", 
"Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", "Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg", 
"Prepared Salad, Fruit & Veg"), period = 201904:201909, how = c("a_tslm_mape", 
"a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape", "a_tslm_mape"
)), .Names = c("forecast", "actual", "BC", "period", "how"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: How large is your *df* in columns and rows: `dim(df)`? Try reducing rows and test. ODBC driver might be imposing limits.

Comment: @Parfait I tried writing single row but it doesn't help. I was able to insert a row using **sqlQuery** command manually giving values but **sqlSave** is not working

Comment: Can you answer my first question? And by reducing rows, I meant saving first few rows: `sqlSave(ch, head(df, 10), tablename = paste("scenario.table_storetype"),rownames=F)`. Your issue may be a size restriction.

Comment: @Parfait the dimension of df is [396, 5]

Comment: Do you have nested objects inside data.frame like lists? Please post the `dput(head(df))` so we can see its properties/dimensions.

Comment: @Parfait Please find the output for __dput(head(df))__ above

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have very large numbers with varying degrees of precision. When creating the table dynamically, the numeric fields may map over as [`DECIMAL(n, m)`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/WurHmDcDf31smikPbo9Mcw/qRPNDX~qEo95bZ~BnM5UaA) types where the scale of 2 may be set by the first value, `36659805.75` but this later conflicts with `33650734.4166667` with scale of 7.

Consider using the *varTypes* argument of [`sqlSave`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) to explicitly define the data types. Per the docs:

> **varTypes:** an optional named character vector giving the DBMSs datatypes to be used for some (or all) of the columns if a table is to be created

Additionally, round accordingly in R to adhere to precision needs of the Teradata column types

```
df$forecast <- round(df$forecast, 4)           # PRECISION OF 4

max(nchar(df$BC))                              # FIND MAX CHARS
max(nchar(df$how))                             # FIND MAX CHARS

tbl_types = c(forecast = "DECIMAL(12, 4)",
              actual = "DECIMAL(12, 4)",
              BC = "VARCHAR(50)",
              period = "INTEGER",
              how = "VARCHAR(20)")

sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = paste("scenario.table_storetype"), 
        varTypes = tbl_types, rownames = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried rounding off and giving  varTypes  argument to  sqlSave  but it didn't help

Comment: Same exact error? Try this. Send a few columns into the `sqlSave` to see which fails: `sqlSave(ch, df[c("BC", "how")], ...)` (varchar fields), `sqlSave(ch, df[c("period")], ...)` (int field), `sqlSave(ch, df[c("forecast", "actual")], ...)` (numeric fields).

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Parfait. But nothing seems to be working